# App shows up as installed on playstore when it isn't

Tags: android, wear-os

Not sure where to begin debugging this problem, but I am writing a companion app on wear os.
But the issue is that play store (on the phone), seems to think the app is still installed on the watch, even after uninstalling. Has anyone else encountered this before?

[playstore showing app as installed when it is not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJUCC.png)

I've ensured that the watch is synced to the phone, and I've also tried closing/ reopening the play store application with no success.